# Being $G_1\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ and $G_2\subseteq \Bbb R^m$ open sets, show that $G_1\times G_2\subseteq \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$ is open set.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory

Let $G_1\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ and $G_2\subseteq \Bbb R^m$ be open sets, then show that $G_1\times G_2\subseteq \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$ is an open set.

Dem:

Given that $G_1,G_2$ open sets, there exists $B_1(g_1,\epsilon)\subseteq  G_1$ and $B_2(g_2,\epsilon')\subseteq G_2$, and by the definition of cartesian product we have that:

$$B_1(g,\epsilon)\times B_2(g',\epsilon')\subseteq G_1\times G_2 $$

So let $\gamma\in B_1(g,\epsilon)\times B_2(g',\epsilon')$:

$\implies \gamma=(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2: \forall g_1\in B_1(g_1,\epsilon)$ and $\forall g'_2\in B_2(g',\epsilon')$

Can you guide through this? I still don't get the subject. I'll appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray, is that really a well-defined topology? I don't think I've heard of it before. I'm not sure that the way you've described it gives you closure under finite intersections - for example if $X = Y = \Bbb R$, let $A_1, A_2 \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ be two disjoint open annuli around $0$. Then $A_1 \cup \{0\}$ and $A_2 \cup \{0\}$ have open projections, but their intersection, $\{0\}$, does not. Were you thinking of the product topology?

Comment: It looks like the $\varepsilon$-ball definition is used to define open sets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you are using the Euclidean metrics throughout. This doesn't matter a whole lot to the thrust of the argument, but it may make it easier to follow. Let $d_n $ be the metric for $\mathbb{R}^n $, $d_m $ the metric for $\mathbb{R}^m $, and $d$ the metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m} $  defined by $$d^2 [(x,y), (a,b)] =d_n^2 (x,a) +d_m ^2 (y,b)$$ for $x, a\in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $y,b\in \mathbb{R}^m $.

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in G_1\times G_2$, with $x_0\in G_1 $ and $y_0\in G_2 $. Since $G_1 $ is open, there exists $\epsilon _1 $ such that if $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d_n(x_0, x)<\epsilon _1 $ then $x\in G_1 $. Since $G_2 $ is open, there exists $\epsilon _2 $ such that if $y\in \mathbb{R}^m $ and $d_m (y_0, y) <\epsilon _2 $, then $y\in G_2$.
Let $\epsilon =\min\{\epsilon _1 ,\epsilon _2  \}$. Suppose that $d[(x,y),(x_0,y_0)]<\epsilon$. Then $$d_n^2(x,x_o) \leq d_n ^2 (x,x_0 )+d_m ^2 (y,y_0)=d^2[(x,y),(x_0,y_0)]<\epsilon ^2 \leq \epsilon _1 ^2 .$$
Thus, $x\in G_1 $. Analogously, $y\in G_2 $. Hence, $(x,y)\in G_1\times G_2 $ and so the open ball of radius $\epsilon $ centered at $(x_0, y_0)$ is in $G_1\times G_2 $. Since $(x_0, y_0)$ was arbitrary, $G_1\times G_2 $ is open.